# getting an elements of the matrix in efficient way with itertools help in python

Tags: python, matrix, python-itertools

I faced an problem of getting elements that i need from matrix(list of lists) using itertools.
I can easily do it using a simple for loop but im interested in more efficient way.

so i have a list of lists(lets call it matrix) and list of indices that refers to needed element in each list from matrix
something like this:

```
matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
line = [0,1,2,0,0]
```

so expected output should be iterable: 0 4 8 9 12

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate also

```
matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
line = [0,1,2,0,0]

res = [matrix[count][i] for count, i in enumerate(line) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
line = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]

r = []
for i in range(len(line)):
    r.append(matrix[i][line[i]])

print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.getitem` combined with `map`:

```
import operator
result = map(operator.getitem, matrix, line)
```